# A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database, An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.

Tags: java, playframework, oracle10g

I am tying to connect oracle10g with my application in play framework. But when I am running my application from command prompt it is throwing the following error -

```
19:53:22,344 ERROR ~ Cannot connected to the database : An attempt by a client t
o checkout a Connection has timed out.

java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
        at play.db.DBPlugin.onApplicationStart(DBPlugin.java:143)
        at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:525)
        at play.Play.start(Play.java:526)
```

Here is my configuration for application.conf

```
db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.21.123.99:1521:HERMES
db.user=hermes
db.pass=hermes
```

## Connections pool configuration :

```
db.pool.timeout=15000
db.pool.maxSize=100
db.pool.minSize=10
```

Please help me with this....

Comment: I am not a JAVA person, but looking from what you have, the error seems to be because of invalid connection string. Or even more, it is because of DB is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the launch configuration. Tried running it through eclipse launch configuration, it worked fine